# Executar um método após a conclusão de um método anterior no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Como fazer para que um método só seja executado após a conclusão de outro método? Entendo que em Angular tratamos de forma assíncrona, ou seja, uma linha de código não necessariamente espera a conclusão da anterior para ser executada, também não quero utilizar um  setTimeout() obrigando um método ficar aguardando determinado tempo para ser executado. Abaixo tenho o seguinte código:

```
intervalo: number = 10;
resultado: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  somarValoresIntervalo() {
    for(let x = 1; x < this.intervalo; x++) {
    this.resultado += x;
  }

  imprimirResultadoMultiplicado(){
    this.somarValoresIntervalo();
    console.log(this.resultado*10);
  }
```

}

Quero que o console.log() no método imprimirResultadoMultiplicado() só seja executado após a linha anterior ter sido concluída (independente do tempo que levar). Existe alguma forma para resolver isso através de Obsevable,Subscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o seu problema você pode usar um simples callback

```js
  somarValoresIntervalo(callback) {
    for(let x = 1; x < this.intervalo; x++) {
    this.resultado += x;
    }
    callback()
  }

  imprimirResultadoMultiplicado(){
    this.somarValoresIntervalo(() => console.log(this.resultado*10));
  }
```

Ou você pode criar um Subject para emitir dados.

```js
  import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

  let subject = new Subject<string>();

  somarValoresIntervalo(callback) {
    for(let x = 1; x < this.intervalo; x++) {
    this.resultado += x;
    }
    subject.next(this.resultado);
  }

 subject.subscribe((resultado) => {
   const resultadoMultiplicado = resultado*10;
 });
```

Comment: Ótimo Daniel, vou fazer desta forma.

Comment: Utilizei o primeiro cenário, funcionou perfeitamente.